# add_action and do_action: multiple calls to same callback?

Tags: actions

I have a setup similar to this:

```
function get_type_data($val) {
    // Get the data from the DB where the ID is $val and return it.
}
add_action('my_hook', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
```

I need to repeat this callback for several results of another callback, which I was thinking of doing like this:

```
// Get the types first, then...
foreach ($type as $val) {
    add_action('my_hook', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
    do_action('my_hook', $val);
}
```

But it only does the first one. I then did it as follows:

```
// Get the types first, then...
foreach ($type as $val) {
    add_action('my_hook_' . $val, array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
    do_action('my_hook_' . $val, $val);
}
```

I figured that this would then create sort of a dynamic hook and add the same action to it, but use the new parameter. Again, it only does the first one.

Then, just as a test, I did it like this:

```
add_action('my_hook_1', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook_1', 1);

add_action('my_hook_2', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook_2', 2);

add_action('my_hook_3', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook_3', 3);
```

Again, it only did the first one.

Finally, I did it like this, to see if I can call the same hook with different parameters:

```
add_action('my_hook', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook', 1);

add_action('my_hook', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook', 2);

add_action('my_hook', array($this, 'get_type_data'), 10, 1);
do_action('my_hook', 3);
```

I also tried with different priority values as the third parameter to add_action. Nothing works for me.

I failed to find resources indicating how this can be done. Even if it worked, the last two can't be a solution, as the data is dynamic from a web service.

**Edit:**

As requested by @Sally CJ, a bit more info:

- I am trying to run that hook several times for different values.
- I have, let's say two categories (but could be more) that need to run to populate a local database with data from a REST service. I first make a call to the REST service to get the categories back. Then for each of the categories returned, I need to call `get_type_data` with each category ID and pull all the data from the REST service for that category, and add it to a local database.
- The result set is too large to let multiple users run the rest service on demand, so I am running that via a cron job to return and prep the data (it only changes every hour or so), and then each user can get their subsection of the data on demand from a local database.

Let's say my categories returned are 1 and 2. When doing any of the loops, only data with `category_id` 1 are returned, similar to:

```
// Result from call 1
[
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Sample 1'
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Sample 2'
    ]    
]

// Result from call 2 never happening.
```

Where I was expecting results like this:

```
// Result from call 1
[
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Sample 1'
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Sample 2'
    ]    
]

// Result from call 2.
[
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Sample 1'
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Sample 2'
    ]    
]
```

I can confirm the data is available when I swop the statements around (so the second one brings data, and the first one then does not).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your snippets, apart from the 3rd one (which contains a typo - `'my_hook_' , $val` should be `'my_hook_' . $val`), looked good to me, so, "it only does the first one" - what exactly do you mean by that - can you show a sample `$type` array/values you used and the output of your `foreach` loop (which basically calls `$this->get_type_data( $val )`)? And what are you really trying to do, is it to pass the dynamic `$val` value to the `get_type_data()` method?

Comment: The first code example should be executing subtractive iterations of hooked callbacks - the first hooked callback should execute `n` times (as many times as there are loop iterations), the second hooked callback executing `n-1` times, etc. The second code example is an invalid `add_action()` syntax which should be throwing errors, short of some very unusual edge cases. None of the examples should only be executing just the first hooked callback unless that callback `die()`s or is throwing a fatal PHP error - we need more context to answer the question.

Comment: @SallyCJ - thank you. Added the intended result from what I am trying to do. @bosco, thanks, Sally pointed out the invalid syntax, which I have now resolved in my question. The problem is that the add_action does NOT execute `n` or `n-1` times no matter what I do.

Comment: "so I am running that via a cron job to return" - how did you setup the cron job? Are you using [WP-Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/) - if so, what's your code and why do you need to *manually* call `do_action()`? 

Comment: @SallyCJ - good question, thanks. It started off as two regular cron scripts written in vanilla PHP, but now, I want to do that in Wordpress as I am new to WP, and want to learn sustainably. Once I get it to run, I will know WHY it works and then use the Wp-Cron plugin. I hope that kind-of makes sense for my motivation to do it?

Comment: I see. And as for the "Once I get it to run", you could try adding something like `echo "works for $val<br />"; return;` at the top in the `get_type_data()` method, and see what your loop outputs? Because as I already said, your loop worked fine for me - the "it only does the first one" never happened.

Comment: Yup, for some reason, it only runs once. Here is the output: `Works for 99`. Thanks. I guess I am going to go and do a single cron job, that is called once, and in this cron job, I will retrieve the categories, and loop through them all. I am at the moment unable to see what I am doing wrong, and I am out of time for this project :-)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't notified of your last reply.. :/ anyway, what I had in mind was that you hadn't actually setup any cron jobs and that you're just trying to get the loop working through the normal flow, i.e. not via a cron event's action. So if that's correct, then it's strange that `get_type_data()` only got called for the 1st item, if the categories array (`$type` in the question) actually contained two or more items.. 

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, thank you. I have done the cron job as a single cronjob call, that gets all the types first, and then loops to get the data per type in the same call. This works now. I am at a loss to figure out what I did wrong before, but it is working for now. Thanks for your time!